# Combine grep and factor from different columns in selecting R dataframe rows

Tags: r, regex

I am am changing values in the column df$AccPat in a dataframe based on values in other cells. Starting point:

```
      AccVs               Verb              Acc      LVs AccPat
0         2            pádsáda               fa        1      u
1         1     pácccaiiidncll               ma        2      u
2         0                saa               un        1      u
3         0               liss               un        0      u
4         1           litátoko               fa        0      u
5         1           wupágaak               ma        1      u
```

I can combine multiple factors, thus:

```
df[df$Acc == "fa" & df$LVs == "0",]$AccPat <- "a"

      AccVs               Verb              Acc      LVs AccPat
0         2            pádsáda               fa        1      u
1         1     pácccaiiidncll               ma        2      u
2         0                saa               un        1      u
3         0               liss               un        0      u
4         1           litátoko               fa        0      a
5         1           wupágaak               ma        1      u
```

or I can use grep to choose rows which match a regular expression in one column:

```
df[grep("^pá", df$Verb),]$AccPat <- "p"

      AccVs               Verb              Acc      LVs AccPat
0         2            pádsáda               fa        1      p
1         1     pácccaiiidncll               ma        2      p
2         0                saa               un        1      u
3         0               liss               un        0      u
4         1           litátoko               fa        0      a
5         1           wupágaak               ma        1      p
```

but I would like to do both at the same time, so only choose rows matching the regular expression above that have a value of "1" in df$AccVs.

```
      AccVs               Verb              Acc      LVs AccPat
0         2            pádsáda               fa        1      u
1         1     pácccaiiidncll               ma        2      b
2         0                saa               un        1      u
3         0               liss               un        0      u
4         1           litátoko               fa        0      a
5         1           wupágaak               ma        1      u
```

I used to think this was impossible, but [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41704212/combining-grep-and-a-numerical-comparison-in-r) makes me think it isn't. However, the solution given there does not work for me.

```
df[grep("^pá", df$Verb) & df$AccVs == "1"]$AccPat <- "b"
```

results in the errors "undefined columns selected" and "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length", and

```
df[grep("^pá", df$Verb) & df$AccVs == "1",]$AccPat <- "b"
```

attempts to print my entire dataframe (which is much larger than this sample one), and also results in the error "longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length".

Note: Many of the values I am checking for are strings, so I need a solution that works for strings. I'm not doing anything numeric, so it's fine if I treat the integers as stings.

Comment: I do have a clunky workaround: creating a new column with a flag for matches to the regular expression, then using that as a factor to combine, but it seems like it shouldn't be necessary to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's your data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(AccVs=c(2,1,0,0,1,1), Verb=c("pádsáda","pácccaiiidncll","saa","liss","litátoko","wupágaak"),
                 Acc=c("fa","ma","un","un","fa","ma"),
                 LVs=c(1,2,1,0,0,1),
                 AccPat=rep("u",6),
                 stringsAsFactors=F)
```

`grep` and `==` return different classes:

```
grep("^pá", df$Verb)
[1] 1 2

df$AccVs == "1"
[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Use `grepl` to return `logical`

```
grepl("^pá", df$Verb)
[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

The result:

```
  AccVs           Verb Acc LVs AccPat
1     2        pádsáda  fa   1      u
2     1 pácccaiiidncll  ma   2      b
3     0            saa  un   1      u
4     0           liss  un   0      u
5     1       litátoko  fa   0      u
6     1       wupágaak  ma   1      u
```

Comment: grepl is exactly what I needed, and I didn't know that existed. If you make that an answer, I will accept it!